# How can I get the result of cost base on Effective Date?

Tags: sql, ssms

Now I have TableB AS B

```
(Date, Store, Product, Qty)
('4/1/20', '1', 'A', '5'),
('4/9/20', '2', 'A', '5'),
('4/1/20', '2', 'A', '4'),
('4/1/20', '3', 'B', '3'),
('4/2/20', '3', 'B', '1'),
('4/2/20', '5', 'C', '2')
```

and TableD AS D

```
(Product, Effective, Cost)
('A', '4/1/20', '100'),
('A', '4/8/20', '120'),
('B', '4/1/20', '100'),
('B', '4/8/20', '110'),
('C', '4/1/20', '100')
```

**I want to SUM(B.Qty * D.Cost) AS TotalCOst
But need to base on Effective date too.**

ex IF Date is '4/1/20' for Store 1 Product A so TotalCost is 5*100 = 500
But if Date is '4/9/20' for Store 1 Produst A so TotalCost is 5*120 = 600

Can you guide me with this please.

This is what I have try but the result still now correct.

```
  SELECT
          B.Date,
          D.Effective,
          Datediff(DAY, B.Date, D.Effective) AS Datediff,
          B.Store,
          B.Product,
          SUM(D.Cost) AS Cost,
          SUM(D.Cost * B.Qty) AS TotalCost,
          CASE WHEN Datediff(DAY, D.Effective, B.Date) >= 0
               THEN SUM(D.Cost)
               ELSE 0
          END AS Cost_Temp,
          CASE WHEN Datediff(DAY,  D.Effective, B.Date) >= 0
               THEN SUM(D.Cost * B.Qty)
               ELSE 0
          END AS TotalCost_Temp
    FROM
          TableB AS B
          INNER JOIN TableD AS D
                 ON B.Product = D.Product
GROUP BY
          B.Date,
          B.Store,
          B.Product,
          D.Effective
ORDER BY
          B.Date
```

Comment: Side note: If possible, never store dates as string. Use valid date type.

Comment: Please add the expected result

Comment: Also, *never* write dates using 2 digits; learn from the Y2K bug, we don't need a Y2.1k bug as well.

Comment: SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is an IDE-like application not a data engine; what data engine are you using? That you are using SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Try to avoid keywords like `DATE` and `DATEDIFF` as column names.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, does this at least help? https://dbfiddle.uk/bOwzsLY- You should clarify your requirements...As said, you need to fix your data types and namings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is finding the effective price. This can be done in SQL Server using an `OUTER APPLY`. What we want to do in words is select the most recent rate that was in effect on the date in table D. (I'm assuming this is some sort of sales date, I guess.)

We get that by the simple query

```
SELECT  TOP 1  -- Because we only want the most recent
        D.COST
  FROM
        TableD AS D
 WHERE
        D.EFFECTIVE <= B.DATE  -- Only those prices that could be in effect
   AND  D.PRODUCT = B.PRODUCT  -- Only the product of interest
   AND  D.STORE = B.STORE      -- Only the store of interest
ORDER BY D.EFFECTIVE  DESC     -- To make sure the most recent is first
;
```

So, making the above a sub-select in the `OUTER APPLY` you get the row you need. The case statements are no longer necessary, I think.

#### The Answer

```
SELECT
        B.[DATE]
       ,D.EFFECTIVE
       ,DATEDIFF( DAY, B.[DATE], D.EFFECTIVE ) AS 'DATEDIFF'
       ,B.STORE
       ,B.PRODUCT
       ,SUM( D.COST ) AS 'COST'
       ,SUM( D.COST * B.QTY ) AS 'TOTAL_COST'
  FROM
        TableB B
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 *
                        FROM TableD D1
                       WHERE B.PRODUCT = D1.PRODUCT
                         AND B.[DATE] >= D1.EFFECTIVE
                     ORDER BY D1.EFFECTIVE DESC ) D
GROUP BY
          B.[DATE],
          B.STORE,
          B.PRODUCT,
          D.EFFECTIVE
ORDER BY
          B.[DATE]
;
```

#### More

A nice way to test this would be to run the following query which shows the row-by-row comparison. You can see which effective date was chosen and which cost was used for each row in TableA.

```
SELECT
        B.[DATE]
       ,D.EFFECTIVE
       ,DATEDIFF( DAY, B.[DATE], D.EFFECTIVE ) AS 'DATEDIFF'
       ,B.STORE
       ,B.PRODUCT
       ,D.COST
       ,B.QTY
       ,D.COST * B.QTY      AS 'TOTAL_COST'
  FROM
        TableB AS B
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 *
                        FROM TableD AS D1
                       WHERE B.PRODUCT = D1.PRODUCT
                         AND B.[DATE] >= D1.EFFECTIVE
                     ORDER BY D1.EFFECTIVE DESC ) D
ORDER BY
          B.[DATE]
;
```

Here's what I get from that:

```
+------------+------------+----------+-------+---------+--------+-----+------------+
|    DATE    | EFFECTIVE  | DATEDIFF | STORE | PRODUCT |  COST  | QTY | TOTAL_COST |
+------------+------------+----------+-------+---------+--------+-----+------------+
| 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-01 |        0 |     2 | A       | 100.00 |   4 |     400.00 |
| 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-01 |        0 |     3 | B       | 100.00 |   3 |     300.00 |
| 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-01 |        0 |     1 | A       | 100.00 |   5 |     500.00 |
| 2020-04-02 | 2020-04-01 |       -1 |     3 | B       | 100.00 |   1 |     100.00 |
| 2020-04-02 | 2020-04-01 |       -1 |     5 | C       | 100.00 |   2 |     200.00 |
| 2020-04-09 | 2020-04-08 |       -1 |     2 | A       | 120.00 |   5 |     600.00 |
+------------+------------+----------+-------+---------+--------+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Your code is really useful! But I still got a problem after I run this code.

As you can see in TableD for Product C after EffDate the cost change to 150 but in the result still show the Product C Cost on Date 4/15/20 in 100 not 150.

@StoneGiant

Comment: @Nymph, I don't see any dates beyond 4/9/2020 in your data. So, I'm not sure what problem you are experiencing.